# Is my proof for $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}=0$ correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

[Here](http://richardhaskell.com/files/Special%20Relativity%20and%20Maxwells%20Equations.pdf), Richard Haskell proves the Lorentz force using Lorentz transformations. Equation $(92)$ mentions the formula for $\vec{B}$ as follows,
$$\vec{B}=\frac{\gamma}{c^{2}}\left(\vec{v}×\vec{E'}\right)......(1)$$
Where,
$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$ and
$\vec{v}$ , $\vec{E'}$ are velocity and electric field in moving frame of reference respectively.
Now applying divergence on both sides of $(1)$,
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}=\frac{\gamma}{c^{2}}\left(\vec{\nabla}\cdot\left(\vec{v}×\vec{E'}\right)\right)$$
By properties of cross product we have that,
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\left(\vec{v}×\vec{E'}\right)=\vec{E'}\cdot \left(\vec{\nabla}×\vec{v}\right)=0$$
Implying that,
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}=0$$
Hence proved.

I was just thinking if this proof is true?

Answer (score 2):

$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ is an empirical formula based on the fact that magnetic monopoles are not observed to exist and therefore magnetic field lines always form closed loops.  This is not able to be derived from other equations, particularly those for Lorentz boosts of electromagnetic fields.  Your result is not a proof of $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ but rather a consistency check that this law is built into the mechanics of the Lorentz boost formula.

Comment: Well, if that formula is consistent with Lorentz transformations doesn't that mean Lorentz transformations imply the non existence of magnetic monopoles?